# Building a scroll view page for iPhone application

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I need to develop a scroll view screen for iPhone. I have done a screen design in interface builder, and I ran the program on the simulator but I'm unable to scroll the page.

Following steps I used to design the page
inside interface builder

select all, then I went to Layout > Embed Objects In ... > scrollview)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to make the `contentSize` of the scroll view bigger than the frame size to scroll. Also don't forget to enable `scrollEnabled`.

Take a look at the [UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) where you also find some links to related sample code.